# Negative powers of matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

For any matrix $A$ is it true that, $A^{-n} = (A^{-1})^n = (A^n)^{-1}$?

Does this also then apply to powers of diagonalizable matrices? That is, if $A = PDP^{-1}$ then $A^{-n} = PD^{-n}P^{-1}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For sure this is true. By the way how would you define $A^{-n}$ if not with the given formulas? The second equality can be easily deduced from the first ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If $A$ is an invertble square matrix, then we have $A^{-n} := (A^{-1})^n = (A^n)^{-1}$ for all natural $n$, which can easily be proved by induction.

If $A$ is diagoalizable and $A = PDP^{-1}$, then again by induction, we have $A^{-n} = PD^{-n}P^{-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N.$

Answer (score 0):

In view of the first question, for each commutative ring $R$, if $a\in R$ is invertible, then define the negative powers as
$a^{-n} = (a^{-1})^n$, $n\geq 0$.

The equation $(a^{-1})^n = (a^n)^{-1}$ needs a proof (by induction on $n$).

Comment: Commutativity is not needed, as $a$ commutes with all its powers.